# Confused how the SVD calculation chooses the correct axes to project onto

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, svd

I'm learning about singular value decomposition, and I think I have a decent understanding of how $A = U \Sigma V ^{T}$ is derived, but I'm having trouble understanding how the actual calculation chooses the "best" singular value axes to project $A$ onto.

In order to calculate the matrices $U$, $\Sigma$, and $V ^{T}$, I first solve for the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A^{T}A$.  From my -- admittedly not great -- understanding of eigenvectors, the eigenvectors of $A^{T}A$ are then used to construct $V$, as in the formula $A^{T}AV = U\Sigma^2$.

Now the formula $AV = U\Sigma$ is projecting $A$ onto $V$, right?

Assuming everything I've said is correct, I'm confused why $V$, which is an eigenbasis for $A^{T}A$, is able to be used as the axes to project $A$ onto in the singular value decomposition.  To put it another way; why are we able to use eigenvectors of $A^{T}A$ as eigenvectors of $A$?

I'm probably wrong about something that I've stated above, but I'm not sure what.

**EDIT**: I realize my original question was unclear, so here's what I hope is a better explanation:

Here is a graph of the $V$ matrix for the SVD of a set of four 2-dimensional points.  The first vector in $V$ gives the axis that $A$ should be projected onto to give the maximum variance between points in $A$.  The second axis in $V$ is orthogonal to the first axis.

So my question is: how does the SVD calculation "know" how to choose the best axes to project onto?  Since $V$ is constructed from the eigenvectors of $A^{T}A$, how does that result in the best projection axes for $A$?  In other words, how does the SVD calculation know to pick this specific set of orthogonal vectors, instead of any other set of orthogonal vectors that results in a worse SVD projection of $A$?

[image]

Comment: The eigenvectors of $A^{T}A$ aren't the eigenvectors of $A$  as $A$ is typically non-square. They're called the right singular vectors.

Comment: Then what I don't understand is since $V$ is constructed with the the eigenvectors of $A^{T}A$ (and not $A$), why is $V$ then the best basis to project $A$ onto (assuming I'm correct that that's what's going on)?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2691/making-sense-of-principal-component-analysis-eigenvectors-eigenvalues

Comment: The SVD is unique up to sign of the vectors in $V$ and $U$...it's not like it's choosing anything.

Comment: some edits...showing the choice of reflector $F$

Answer (score 1):

This may not answer your question as much

> Assuming everything I've said is correct, I'm confused why $V$, which is
>   an eigenbasis for $A^{T}A$, is able to be used as the axes to project A
>   onto in the singular value decomposition. To put it another way; why
>   are we able to use eigenvectors of $A^{T}A$ as eigenvectors of $A$?

They're not eigenvectors. They're the right singular vectors because a non-square matrix doesn't have eigenvectors.

> In order to calculate the matrices $U$, $\Sigma$, and $V ^{T}$, I
>   first solve for the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A^{T}A$.  From my
>   -- admittedly not great -- understanding of eigenvectors, the eigenvectors of $A^{T}A$ are then used to construct $V$, as in the
>   formula $A^{T}AV = U\Sigma^2$.

This doesn't work. Note that if I take $$A^{T}AV V^{*}  = U \Sigma^{2} V^{*} \\ A^{T}A = U \Sigma^{2} V^{*}  = U \Lambda V^{*} $$

The steps are

$ \textrm{1. Form }  A^{*}A $

$ \textrm{2. Compute the eigenvalue decomposition of }  A^{*}A  = V \Lambda V^{*} $

$ \textrm{3. Let }   \Sigma  \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}  $ be the non-negative diagonal square root of $\Lambda$

$ \textrm{4. Solve the system }   U\Sigma = AV $ for the unitary $U$ (e.g. using the QR factorization)

How is this done? There are few ways to accomplish it. One way is using Householder reflectors but you could simply form the eigendecomp of $AA^{T} = U \Lambda U^{*}$ and take $U$ but I'm pretty this isn't a good method computationally.

[image]

If you're taking numerical linear algebra this is the same way you get the matrix to Hessenberg form.

> So my question is: how does the SVD calculation "know" how to choose
>   the best axes to project onto?  Since $V$ is constructed from the
>   eigenvectors of $A^{T}A$, how does that result in the best projection
>   axes for $A$?  In other words, how does the SVD calculation know to
>   pick this specific set of orthogonal vectors, instead of any other set
>   of orthogonal vectors that results in a worse SVD projection of $A$?

The SVD is unique up to the sign of the vectors in $U,V$. It isn't choosing anything. In the actual computation you successfully apply Householder reflectors. What do they look like?

Like above this is called bidiagonalization. We take $A$ and do the following.

$$ Q_{n}\cdots Q_{1} A = R  $$

Thus $A=QR$ ...It looks like this...[image]

Where $Q_{k}$ is given as

$$ Q_{k} = \begin{pmatrix} I & 0 \\ 0 & F \end{pmatrix} $$

$I \in \mathbb{C}^{(k-1) \times (k-1)}$ is an identity matrix and $ F \in \mathbb{C}^{(m-k+1) \times (m-k+1)} $ is a unitary matrix. When we apply this reflector $F$ to a vector $x \in \mathbb{C}^{m-k+1}$ it zeros everything most of the vector.

$$  x  = \begin{pmatrix}  x_{1} \\ \vdots \\ x_{m-k+1} \end{pmatrix}  \stackrel{F}{\to} Fx  = \begin{pmatrix}  \|x \| \\ 0 \\  \vdots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

this can be written also as $Fx = \|x\|e_{1}$ where $e_{1}$ is the $(m - k+1)$  dimensional vector given as $ e_{1} = (1 , 0, \cdots, 0)^{T}$

The extension to this is called Golub-Kahan Bidiagonalization...

$$ A \to U_{n}^{*} \cdots U_{1}^{*} A V_{1} \cdots V_{m} $$

for an $ n \times m$ matrix for instance. Each of these reflectors $F$ can be seen as reflecting the space $\mathbb{C}^{m-k+1}$ across a hyper-plane orthogonal to $v = \|x\| e_{1} -x$. This can be defined as

$$  F = I - 2\frac{vv^{*}}{v^{*}v}$$